# Parsing blog post

Tags: java, android

Let's say I am making a blog application about news. Whole idea is getting blog posts and showing them in application. I am parsing posts from RSS feed. 
Every blog post has some amount of text,some pictures and a youtube video. I want to show everything exactly like in website. But all I can do is showing only text in text view:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/postContent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:textColor="@color/postTextColor"/>
```

In post view activity:

```
final TextView mPostContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postContent);
mPostContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(content).toString().replace("￼","").replace('\r', ' '));
```

This helps me to show text only. But as I mentioned blog post have more than one images. What should I do? Using webview is not a solution.

Comment: use markdown syntax and try something like this https://github.com/falnatsheh/MarkdownView

Comment: @Blundell it's not ordinary web view?

Comment: Let's say you post a good question. Whole idea is reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @NoiseGenerator I know how to ask questions. I just can't form my idea correctly. That's all.

Comment: It actually seems you don't, Where's your effort? What's your code? Did you search for any solution?

Comment: @NoiseGenerator updated question. Yes I did. But I don't know what should I search for. I wanted to try dynamically adding image views and text views but it's not a good solution

Comment: Google for `android rss feed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse all the data using the RSS feeds and create a specific screen to display this parsed data the way you like.

Comment: I already did. But all I can do is displaying text. But the page has images too. And they are placed randomly. I want to show them exactly like a blogpost

Comment: Ok. When you say exactly like a blogspot you mean the text and the images respecting the same order of view like text, image, text, text, image something like that right? Adjusting to the resolution like a responsive site?

Comment: No. They are placed randomly in random amount. For example one post can have 5 images another one can have no images

Comment: I think you can create a api that will return text_blocks and images in the sequence they need to appear for a specific blog_post_id and just create a data viewer for this format in your app.

Answer (score 0):

It depends by the object format of your posts variable, maybe can it helps an adapter to a recyclerView and a CardView with the adapter class the with json or xml parser get the from the api response objects

Comment: I am parsing RSS feed. Getting a html text in response.